# Add the cubes on specific keyframe

Tags: python, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have a grid 8x8 of cubes and I would that each cube fall down one by one and I imagine that each cube had to assign on a specific keyframe but I don't know how to do in python bpy. Below there is the code that I work with, maybe someone has an idea.

Thank you in advance

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

mass = 1000
f = 0.8
d = 0.999
start_frame = 0
delta = 14400

Dn = 1
nx = 8
ax = 1.2
ny = 8
by = 1.2

x0 = -4.2
y0 = -4.2
z0 = 3.

cube_mesh = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.context.active_object.dimensions = (1,1,1)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') 
cube = bpy.data.objects['Cubo']              
cube.select_set(True)                        
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube 

bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()               


rigid_body = cube.rigid_body
rigid_body.type = 'ACTIVE'
rigid_body.mass = mass
rigid_body.friction = f
rigid_body.linear_damping = d

xx = np.arange(x0, x0+ax*Dn*nx, ax*Dn)
yy = np.arange(y0, y0+by*Dn*ny, by*Dn)
data = []

for x in xx:
    for y in yy:
        data.append([x,y,z0,np.random.randint(0,120)])

print('data',data)
lines = len(data)

for line in range(lines):
    pos = data[line][:3]
    delay = data[line][3]
    print('pos', pos)
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    obj.location = pos

    obj.rigid_body.enabled = True
    obj.hide_viewport = False
    obj.rigid_body.linear_damping = d
    
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='hide_viewport', frame=start_frame)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='rigid_body.enabled', frame=start_frame)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='rigid_body.linear_damping', frame=start_frame)

    obj.rigid_body.enabled = False
    obj.hide_viewport = False

    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='hide_viewport', frame=start_frame + delay)    
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rigid_body.enabled",frame=start_frame + delay)

    obj.rigid_body.enabled = True
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport",frame=start_frame + delay + 1)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rigid_body.enabled",frame=start_frame + delay + 1)

obj.select_set(False)

cube.select_set(True)   
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Comment: Why isn’t this code working? What happens?

Comment: Sorry, I have set italian language on blender so to make the code working you have to switch 'Cubo' with 'Cube'

Comment: What I mean is that you didn’t have any output of the code. What’s going wrong? I don’t want to just try to run it myself, because I might not have things set up quite the same way as you, and just synchronizing our set ups will probably take as long if not longer than solving the problem.

Comment: If you run it from blender the output is a grid of cubes 8x8 while if you run it from another debugging program you will not get any graphical output. Thak you!

Comment: After a brief review, it sounds like the code is working properly, but you don’t know how to pull a unique value to set the keyframes at for each cube in the loop, so they end up falling at the same time. Is that correct? What should define when the cubes fall? Is it just random?

Comment: Yes, it does. Now the cubes fall down almost at the same time and the only two parameters that define theyr fall are the "start_keyframe" and the "delay", I think so. The outcome that I expect at the end is a blender simulation where the cubes fall down one by one.

Comment: Would it be easier to share your file (or a representative sample) on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: When should the second cube fall? After the first has landed somewhere, or after some other specified delay?

Comment: I think the second cube falling and so on it should be defined by a specific delay. For me it is the better solution. Thank you!